# Downloading 37k records to Android POS device

Tags: android, database, sqlite, retrofit, android-contentprovider

I am working on a Android Based POS system.
Initially I have to download 37K records and store it in DB during first run of the application.
The API returns 100 items per page so there are around 378 pages.
right now I am using retrofit 1.9 and making multiple request and when I get the response I am starting multiple AsyncTask on AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, I am accessing the DB via a content provider that I have written separately.
Problem is that my approach is failing to download all the records , Max it has downloaded 7K records.
For fetching records I am doing a head req to get count of Items and then starting a loop to make multiple request so around 378 request is being made from my side.
Can anyone tell me the better approach ? or help me find issue in my current one ?

**EDIT :-**

I am counting the number of response , I am decrementing the counter for it , but I am facing one interesting thing , GC is getting called many times , can anyone explain me the reason behind this. Intially I used Executor with retrofit to make parallel calls, when I used number of fixed thread equal to numbers of available processors the counter stopped at 310, when i used number of threads equal to 3 counter has stopped at counter 226 , right now i have commented the code for DB insertion, here is how I am creating RestAdapter for retrofit :-

```
  private static RestAdapter restAdapter;
    public static Object getApi(Class mclass){
        if(restAdapter==null){
            restAdapter=new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(UrlUtils.MAIN_URL)
                    .setExecutors(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3),Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()).build();
        }
        return restAdapter.create(mclass);
    }
```

```
 06-30 16:41:55.290 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 285
    06-30 16:41:59.110 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 284
    06-30 16:41:59.700 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 283
    06-30 16:42:01.970 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 282
    06-30 16:42:02.920 27807-27872/com.bewo.app.inventory D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2056K, 34% free 4352K/6572K, paused 27ms, total 29ms
    06-30 16:42:03.430 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 281
    06-30 16:42:05.780 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 280
    06-30 16:42:09.020 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 279
    06-30 16:42:10.260 27807-27873/com.bewo.app.inventory D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1980K, 33% free 4419K/6572K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
    06-30 16:42:10.260 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 278
    06-30 16:42:11.480 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 277
    06-30 16:42:14.500 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 276
    06-30 16:42:15.350 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 275
    06-30 16:42:17.990 27807-27873/com.bewo.app.inventory D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2062K, 33% free 4404K/6572K, paused 62ms, total 62ms
    06-30 16:42:18.680 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 274
    06-30 16:42:20.400 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 273
    06-30 16:42:22.810 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 272
    06-30 16:42:24.180 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 271
    06-30 16:42:26.020 27807-27828/com.bewo.app.inventory D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2072K, 34% free 4379K/6572K, paused 44ms, total 44ms
    06-30 16:42:26.290 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 270
    06-30 16:42:27.920 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 269
    06-30 16:42:29.530 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 268
    06-30 16:42:31.830 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 267
    06-30 16:42:33.420 27807-27828/com.bewo.app.inventory D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2070K, 34% free 4356K/6572K, paused 27ms, total 28ms
    06-30 16:42:33.770 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 266
    06-30 16:42:36.110 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 265
    06-30 16:42:37.770 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 264
    06-30 16:42:39.130 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 263
    06-30 16:42:40.600 27807-27828/com.bewo.app.inventory D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2072K, 35% free 4331K/6572K, paused 26ms, total 27ms
    06-30 16:42:41.200 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 262
    06-30 16:42:43.240 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 261
    06-30 16:42:45.470 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 260
    06-30 16:42:47.310 27807-27828/com.bewo.app.inventory D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1975K, 33% free 4403K/6572K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
    06-30 16:42:47.320 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 259
    06-30 16:42:49.700 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 258
    06-30 16:42:51.390 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 257
    06-30 16:42:53.210 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 256
    06-30 16:42:55.500 27807-27872/com.bewo.app.inventory D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2080K, 34% free 4371K/6572K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
    06-30 16:42:55.770 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 255
    06-30 16:42:57.810 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 254
    06-30 16:43:00.210 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 253
    06-30 16:43:01.630 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 252
    06-30 16:43:03.510 27807-27873/com.bewo.app.inventory D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2066K, 34% free 4353K/6572K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
    06-30 16:43:04.030 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 251
    06-30 16:43:05.910 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 250
    06-30 16:43:08.490 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 249
    06-30 16:43:10.090 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 248
    06-30 16:43:12.080 27807-27828/com.bewo.app.inventory D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2061K, 34% free 4339K/6572K, paused 48ms, total 48ms
    06-30 16:43:12.840 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 247
    06-30 16:43:13.470 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 246
    06-30 16:43:15.740 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 245
    06-30 16:43:18.340 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 244
    06-30 16:43:18.830 27807-27828/com.bewo.app.inventory D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2062K, 35% free 4324K/6572K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
    06-30 16:43:20.160 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 243
    06-30 16:43:21.140 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 242
    06-30 16:43:23.080 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 241
    06-30 16:43:25.560 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 240
    06-30 16:43:25.880 27807-27873/com.bewo.app.inventory D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2078K, 35% free 4294K/6572K, paused 38ms, total 38ms
    06-30 16:43:27.670 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 239
    06-30 16:43:29.540 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 238
    06-30 16:43:31.430 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 237
    06-30 16:43:33.470 27807-27828/com.bewo.app.inventory D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1973K, 34% free 4368K/6572K, paused 65ms, total 66ms
    06-30 16:43:33.570 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 236
    06-30 16:43:36.060 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 235
    06-30 16:43:37.410 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 234
    06-30 16:43:39.320 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 233
    06-30 16:43:40.970 27807-27873/com.bewo.app.inventory D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2086K, 35% free 4330K/6572K, paused 31ms, total 32ms
    06-30 16:43:41.240 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 232
    06-30 16:43:43.840 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 231
    06-30 16:43:45.500 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 230
    06-30 16:43:47.470 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 229
    06-30 16:43:48.790 27807-27828/com.bewo.app.inventory D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2086K, 35% free 4291K/6572K, paused 48ms, total 48ms
    06-30 16:43:49.740 27807-27871/com.bewo.app.inventory D/globalCount: 228
```

Answer (score 1):

a few remark points on your approach that I hope it helps.

- first of all, I hope you're doing all this in a Service. Yeah, I know it's a POS system, but nevertheless, use a Service with a foreground notification on it. The main activity can bound to the service and have a "waiting for sync" screen. If the service gets destroyed and didn't finish, it can continue where it finished.
- most of everything u will execute, should occur in a background thread, but AsyncTasks are horrible classes that I never suggest anyone to ever use. Instead configure on Retrofit for the callbacks to happen in a background thread, like following:

.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                 ... your building
            .callbackExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
            .build();`
```

- Do not execute all your requests at the same time, they will most certainly fail. Instead do one at a time with a control/counter so retries are possible and easy to resume.

You could easily do some mapping on the `SharedPreferences`, like a simply `int currentPage` This would work with the following logic:

1. read SharedPrefs `currentPage` (starts at zero)
2. execute request for `currentPage` value
3. on success_callback => add to DB, increment `currentPage` from SharedPrefs and go back to `1.`
4. on fail_callback => check connectivity, re-try, maybe finish service and schedule to re-execute in a couple of minutes.

alternative to SharedPrefs, you could after the head req, fill up the DB with all the requests necessary to complete the sync and on `1.` read next request from DB; and on `3.` remove the successful item from DB.

**edit:** answer to first two comments:

- That comes from own experience. I had a little HTTP server running on Android once that were incapable of connecting to more than two clients at the same time. We gotta be realistic that it's a tiny battery powered wifi device, and you can't just launch 300 requests all at once. They will time-out, it will run out of memory, etc. Doing one (or at least only a few) at the same time will surely increase success rate.
- Retrofit already executes all the HTTP calls on its own thread, but the `Callback` is normally called on the UI thread. By using the `callbackExecutor` you're asking Retrofit to call your callbacks on that thread. That makes sense on your case as all you're doing during callback is adding the returned values to a DB.

Comment: "Do not execute all your requests at the same time, they will most certainly fail. Instead do one at a time with a control/counter so retries are possible and easy to resume." can you please explain why ?

Comment: also I am guessing that Async retrofit calls happens in separate thread ? isn't it ? whats the use of callbackExecutor ? I am also new to retrofit ..

Comment: I've edit my question with answers to your comments. Please check.

Comment: i want callback on main thread , but i want all the processing to happen in different thread ? will that be a problem if i dont provide callBackExecutor ? I am trying to use this : setExecutors(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5), null)

Comment: from your problem description I cannot see why you would want a callback in the main thread. All you're doing is adding values to a DB, there's no reason for this to be on the main thread. `callbackExecutor` can take any type of `Executor` but for DB insert operations a single thread is preferred.

Comment: If I will use single thread, it will make the db insertion sequential and it will take more time , my main motive is to improve the runtime , though it will run only once, but the older implementation done by other guys takes more than 10mins . I really appreciate the patience you are showing with me , let me try with callbackexecutor

Comment: Your biggest bottleneck there is the HTTP requests, not the DB operation. My suggestion (as initial values, but you can certainly fine-tune later) is to start with 7 HTTP requests running in parallel (so after starting 7, you wait one to finish before starting a new one), and the DB operation in a single thread (because DB write operations in multi-thread are not so safe. For performance, I highly suggest you to execute the DB insert for all the 100 items in 1 call; if you use a loop and make 100 calls to the DB inserting 1 item at a time it will be VERY slow.

Comment: I am inserting all the 100 item using bulkInsert() method,and now I am using number of threads which is equal to number of cores in my device, and by checking the logs i can say that its working fine , I'll update here if my results are fine